# Filters & Pagination for group by queries in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Something {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    //@Getters and @Setters
}
```

I need to use **Optional** filters on field1, field2 and group by on field3. I also need to paginate the data and return count(*), and field3 values. The sql query for same is **(without filters)**:

```
select field3, count(*) as number from something  group by field3 LIMIT 0,10;
```

With 1 filter:

```
select field3, count(*) as number from somethhing where field1=:field1 group by field3 LIMIT 0,10;
```

Similiarly, for filters on field1 and field2.

**Problems:**

1. Query to be executed is dependent on number of filters.
2. The return type of query is not an entity.

Due to problem 1,  I cannot use spring data methods which are directly converted to queries. I also cannot use @Query for the same reason. I cannot write 2^n queries in my repository for each possible combination, where n is number of filters.

Due to problem2,

I cannot use specification. I didn't find any solution with the specification for returning a specific set of fields and aggregate functions.

**My Solution So Far:**

I have used entitymanager and created a query depending on the number of paramters.
Now I am using it like this:

```
List<Object[]> resultData = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

It works, but the problem is: It returns List and I have to manually cast the fields to their correct types and create list of desired result.

Can someone help me here. If there is another working solution/approach, please let me know. If working with entityManager is fine, then let me know, what should I do, so that it returns me List instead of List.

Comment: "what should I do, so that it returns me List instead of List." Should that be "`List<Something>` instead of `List<Object[]>`"?

Comment: It does not return List<Something>, it return List<Object[]>. That's the whole issue.

Comment: So if I use List<Something>, I cannot use getters on it. When I use any getter like this:
result.get(0).getField3()  I get following exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.project.model.ResultClass

Answer (score 1):

Specification can be used for aggregate functions. I used it for doing counts.
Here is how I did it for count distinct from joined table. Code is kotlin but comprehendible:

Filtering:

```
val subQuery = query.subquery(Long::class.java)
val subRoot = subQuery.from(SomeJoinEntity::class.java)
val subJoin = subRoot.join<SomeJoinEntity, SomeRootEntity>("joinAttribute", JoinType.LEFT)

val subQueryCount = subQuery.select(cb.countDistinct(subRoot.get<String>("attributeToBeCounted")))
    subQuery.where(cb.equal(root.get<Any>("id"), subJoin.get<Any>("idJoin")))
```

Sorting:

```
val path = root.join<Any, Any>("joinAttribute", JoinType.LEFT)
        .get<String>("attributeToBeCounted")
query.orderBy(cb.asc(cb.countDistinct(path)))
if(query.groupList.isEmpty()) query.groupBy(root.get<Long>("id"))
```

The problem was that if you use group by, the total count of records will be off. Spring team says that specification is only to be used for WHERE clauses, even though the api lets us do grouping by.

Here is the Spring discussion for this subject: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/2376

What I ended up doing is creating a DB View which already had the aggregated result in it and then mapped one new entity to that view.
Now sorting and filtering is simple since the data is already aggregated.

The problem is thought that querying the DB view is a bit slow. I assume since it is always doing the aggregation, even if it is not necessarily needed.

Be aware that mapping an entity to a view will always result in an aggregated query run. Performance will be decreased even we are not specifically filtering for the aggregated result, but for something else.